# Parse call fetch needed before getting its value

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i am new to objective c and i am using parse.com as my database for a social media app. What I am trying to do is grab the post of the user from my POST table. I am using pointers to get the username from my USER table and that comes through fine, as you will see in my code posted below, but when i use fetchifneeded before assigning the UILabel to the post of the user, i receive this error still "Key "Story" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value." i appreciate any help and thank you in advanced, if i didn't make my self clear in anyway ill be more then happy to expand on anything.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    if (indexPath.section == self.objects.count) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoryCell";

    NinetiesCell *cell = (NinetiesCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //for the post of the user
    PFObject *user = object[@"User"];
    [user fetchIfNeeded]; 
    //get username from pointer
    cell.userName.text = user[@"username"];

    PFObject *story = [object objectForKey:@"Story"];
    [story fetchIfNeeded];
    cell.story.text = [object objectForKey:@"Story"];

    // Configure the cell

    NSDate *updated = [object createdAt];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"];

    cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:updated]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's any data for the key `Story`?

Comment: Yes, i had it working before i tweaked it to have a like button.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cell.story.text=story[@"text"] or some other value from the story object?  It doesn't make sense to put a PFObjext into the text field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better option in your case would be to modify your original query to include the "User" and "Story" columns, e.g.

```
[query includeKey:@"User"];
[query includeKey:@"Story"];
```

Then when you reference those columns in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` they will already be populated, no need to call `fetchIfNeeded`.

Comment: You helped me out tremendously and solved my issue, if you would like please hop over to my question and provide this answer, I would like to give you credit.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117331/amandas-relationship-tips-app-with-scroll-performance-issues?noredirect=1#comment218249_117331